# New import to eclipse, suddenly a lot of Java errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been working on an android project, and recently imported to Eclipse at home. Once I imported my project to Eclipse I suddenly have a lot of new java errors, which I didn't have in my previous environment. I have cleaned the import and removed some of the path errors, but I'm not sure what I should do next. I believe that these errors are most likely the result of something I have done stupidly on my part, but I am not sure.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Do you have the Android ADT installed on your Eclipse? It is not part of the base Eclipse code.

Comment: you apparently don't have a target set on this project.

Comment: You should post images where we can see what's wrong, I can't read anything in there. Also you can capture only the active window with Alt + Print Screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have the incorrect SDK installed or you don't have the Android ADT installed on your Eclipse.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: I went to work on a side project after about a month of not touching it. After 2 hours of trying to figure out why it was full of errors, your post made me remember that I had downloaded the android SDK version of eclipse. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check your Android Manifest file and specify correct sdk version. Also check project properties to verify that you are using correct version of android sdk to compile the project. EDIT : If possible send a screenshot of your manifest and android properties dialog for this project.